# How to mock a local variable that's being set in an external method call using Mockito

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, junit5

I have a code similar to this.

```
@Component
public class Example {
  
  @Autowired
  private GreetingService greetService;
    
  public String greet(String name) {
    AtomicReference<SomeCustomClass> temp = new AtomicReference<>(); 
    String greeting = greetService.getGreeting(temp);  // The method sets a value for temp
    if(!Objects.isNull(temp.get())) {return greeting + " " + name;}
    return "Hello, user";
  }

}
```

I know this is a deliberate example but I have a similar usecase which is a complex version of this. I want to test this class for which I want to test the `if` block. Can someone help me understand, how can I test the code inside `if` block.

Comment: there are just too many things that are wrong here, from field injection vs constructor injection to using `AtomicReference` for whatever reason

Comment: Inject a `GreetingService` that sets `temp` to a non-null value.

Comment: GreetingService would be a mocked object right? @AndyTurner how can it set the value of a local variable? Can you elaborate a little.

Comment: @Eugene I just used field injection here for better understanding. :) I used construction injection in my actual code. The project is actually a reactive streams project. Where I'm calling a method that uses WebClient to call an external service. The usecase is something like this, once I get response from WebClient I need to validate it. If validation fails, I still need the response to be returned in someway. So, that's what the reference to AtomicReference is doing. Sorry for the vague example

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69352844/mock-local-variable-in-junit-mockito

Comment: Yeah, that was asked by me. That was the answer I was looking for. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would test this code without touching it. I do want to point out that the code in this question is written in a way which promotes testing of implementation details and not interface of the class. This kind of tests will not support in refactoring because they will break.

I've done some assumptions about the types this coded uses:

```java
@Component
public class GreetingService {

    public String getGreeting(AtomicReference<SomeCustomClass> someCustomClass) {
        return someCustomClass.get().getSomeValue();
    }
}
```

```
public class SomeCustomClass {

    private String someValue;

    public String getSomeValue() {
        return someValue;
    }

    public void setSomeValue(String s) {
        this.someValue = s;
    }
}
```

The plan here is to mock `GreetingService.getGreeting` in a way which lets us to manipulate the `temp` during tests.
The code is using private field injection, this means that we want to boot up Spring with all of its bells and whistles, which is achieved by using `@SpringBootTest` annotation.

When Spring creates our `Example` component we want it to use our mock `GreetingService` for that, this is achieved by declaring a `@MockBean` field in the test.

Now in the tests we want to manipulate `temp` which is passed in to the `GreetingService` from inside of `Example.greet`, for this we can use Mockitos `then(Answer<T>)` method. In the `Answer` we can manipulate the `temp` reference. Here is the final result:

```java
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;

@SpringBootTest
public class ExampleTest {

    @Autowired
    private Example example;

    @MockBean
    private GreetingService greetingService;

    @Test
    public void returnsGreetingByNameIfValueIsNotNull() {
        // arrange
        when(greetingService.getGreeting(any())).then(new Answer<String>() {
            @Override
            public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                SomeCustomClass testSomeCustomClass = new SomeCustomClass();
                testSomeCustomClass.setSomeValue("Aloha");

                AtomicReference<SomeCustomClass> ref = invocation.getArgument(0, AtomicReference.class);
                ref.set(testSomeCustomClass);
                return ref.get().getSomeValue();
            }
        });

        // act
        String result = example.greet("Jon Doe");

        // assert
        assertThat(result).isEqualTo("Aloha Jon Doe");
    }

    @Test
    public void returnsDefaultGreetingIfValueIsNull() {
        // arrange
        when(greetingService.getGreeting(any())).then(new Answer<String>() {
            @Override
            public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                return null;
            }
        });

        // act
        String result = example.greet("Jon Doe");

        // assert
        assertThat(result).isEqualTo("Hello, user");
    }
}
```