# Mock local variable in Junit, Mockito

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm working on a test case for a code using Mockito. The code looks like this,

```
public class Example {
 
 @Autowired
 private HelperService hs; 

 public void someMethod() {
   List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
   hs.addValues(names);
   if(names.size() < 5) {throw new RuntimeException("Invalid names list");}
   return;
 }

}

public class HelperService {

 public void addValues(List<String> names) {
  names.add("alex");
  names.add("harry");
  names.add("james");
  names.add("maria");
  names.add("bob");
 }

}
```

I know this is a contrived example but I have a similar usecase where I cannot modify the existing code. I want to unit test the **Example** class using **Junit**, **Mockito**. How can I test the exception scenario where `names.size()` is < 5.

Comment: Inject a mock HelperService (which adds fewer names) in your test.

Comment: Or even just extend HelperService and override the method, and inject your extension. No need to even mock here.

Comment: What do you mean extend? Could you elaborate? I'm planning to write a UNIT test using Junit & Mockito to mock external dependencies.

Comment: Added examples as an answer.

Comment: Also, mocking external dependencies isn't always necessary.  Sometimes simply providing different ones (via the plain `extends` option shown below) is sufficient when the classes are simple enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you already have a means for setting the `HelperService` field in your test (whether that's by making it a `@SpringBootTest`, using `@InjectMocks`, or something else).  So this will just give options for providing one that will let you do what you want:

1. Extend `HelperService` and inject that:

```java
// Inject this into your class under test
private HelperService hs = new LessThan5NameAddingHelperService();

class LessThan5NameAddingHelperService extends HelperService {
    @Override
    public void addNames( List<String> names ) {
        names.add( "Dave" );
    }
}
```

2. Provide a `mock` `HelperService` which does the same:

```java
// Inject this into your class under test
private HelperService hs;

@Before
public void setupMockHelperService() {
    hs = mock( HelperService.class );

    doAnswer( invocation -> {
        List<String> names = ( List<String> ) invocation.getArguments()[0];
        names.add( "Dave" );
        return null;
    } ).when( hs ).addNames( any() );
}
```

Comment: Both options look good. Just out of curiosity is there any other short & elegant way to achieve the same?

Comment: Unfortunately not if you can't modify the code.  If you could make `HelperService` an `interface` (and make your one in production an implementation) then you could replace it with a lambda: `hs = names -> { names.add("Dave"); };`, or even just `hs = names -> {};`.

Comment: I see. Anyways, both your answers, though a little lengthy, look neat.

Comment: Apologies, I had meant to comment yesterday. The default behaviour of a mock is to do nothing for void methods. So if you don’t need any behaviour (I.e. no names added at all) then you can skip the entire `doAnswer` portion of the second solution and just have `hs = mock( HelperService.class );`